# Avoiding merged cell when find next empty cell in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that opens a document, copies the last row in a certain column and pastes that value into the next empty cell in another workbook that I am having trouble with.  This has worked before, but in this specific document, the first row has cells that are merged and centered, including the column (B), that I want to find the next empty cell and paste the value in.  When i run the code I get a "this operation requires merged cells to be identically sized" message. In the code below, I have tried to change the rowToPaste to 2 (to bypass the first row with the merged cells), which crashes excel. How can I get the macro to bypass the first row when it is checking for the first empty cell or find another way to avoid the identically sized merge cells problem? Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim NextRow As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim vMax As Variant
Dim rowToPaste As Integer
Dim lastRowToPaste As Integer
Dim lastCheckedRow As Integer

Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FY 13 Budgets -- East Coast")
NextRow = wsMaster.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Set wbDATA = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\Michael Palkovitz\My Documents\Test\PDF to excel.xlsm")
With wbDATA.Sheets("8A")
    LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If LastRow > 1 Then
        .Range("B" & LastRow).Copy
        lastRowToPaste = LastRow + 1000
        rowToPaste = lastCheckedRow
        Do
           rowToPaste = rowToPaste + 1
           If IsEmpty(wsMaster.Range("B" & rowToPaste)) Then
               wsMaster.Range("B" & rowToPaste).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
               wsMaster.Range("B" & rowToPaste).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
               lastCheckedRow = rowToPaste
               Exit Do
           End If
        Loop While (rowToPaste < lastRowToPaste)
    End If
End With

wbDATA.Close False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to reply with a comment to your question, but think this will be easier to read as an answer.

There are a few things that need to be cleaned up or clarified.

1. Always require variable declaration. `wsMaster` and `wbData` are not declared. In the VBE, go to Tools --> Options to set this.
2. You declare some row variables as integers and others as longs. Always use longs to avoid overflow errors.
3. You set `lastRowToPaste` to be 1000 greater than `LastRow`. What is the significance of 1000?
4. `NextRow` and `LastRow` have the first letter capitalized. All other variables have a lower-case first letter. You should use a consistent naming convention.
5. What is the purpose of `NextRow`? You set its value, and then never use it.
6. You set `rowToPaste` equal to `lastCheckedRow`, an variable that hasn't itself been initialized. It's default value is 0, so `rowToPaste` is 0. In the first iteration of you `Do...Loop`, you increment rowToPaste by 1, so the first time through, it equals 1, which is the cause of your error.

To get past that, make these changes to your code:

Change

```
rowToPaste = lastCheckedRow
```

to this:

```
rowToPaste = 2
```

and increment rowToPaste at the end of the loop instead of the beginning:

```
    ...
    End If
    rowToPaste = rowToPaste + 1
Loop While (rowToPaste < lastRowToPaste)
```

Comment: the line with the error is                                  'wsMaster.Range("B" & rowToPaste).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues'.       i appreciate the advice on other coding tips, I am still in the beginning of my learning process on writing code. in this situation if I can bypass the first row of data I believe the error will not occur, but I am not sure how to do that

Comment: bypass the first row in my 'if IsEmpty' statement that is.

Comment: thanks for the help, hopefully as I keep writing code I will get better at finding corrections like this myself so I won't have to bug you guys!

Comment: You're very welcome, and you aren't bugging anyone. We've all been where you are. Enjoy the journey!